# Javascript/jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code works perfectly to do what I want in jsfiddle, but I cannot replicate it when doing it on my local files i.e. index.html, index.css, index.js. Could someone be kind enough to outline how I can make it work locally and not just on jsfiddle?
this is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Naush/Cr7GK/

Here is what I *think* it should look like:

Html:

```
<html>

<head>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="black"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
.black {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.orange {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:orange;
    left:200px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".black").hover(function () {
        $(".orange").toggle();
    })
})
```

I have a STRONG feeling that I'm not including something properly in the html head tag. The file paths are correct, I have double checked. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: have you included jquery?

Comment: This is really basic, but have you linked to JQuery in your <head>?

Comment: Are you actually including jQuery somewhere in code you omitted?  It's a library, you have to include it, the browser doesn't know it by default.

Comment: Look at your browser's console. See if there's any errors being thrown. See if any HTTP 404's are given for the external files. Otherwise, it should work fine like the fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you haven't linked to jQuery in your `<head>` - JSfiddle does it automatically, but you have to do it yourself normally.

Just include this in you `<head>`

`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>`

Here's a working version http://fotest.co.nf/

Comment: Even after doing this, which I admit I forgot to include in this code but had in my other file, the javascript still refuses to work.

Comment: I made a mistake and used href instead of src - it works now for me.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FiXxKwRX works for me

Comment: If it works for you somewhere online, it doesn't mean it will work for OP locally, OP already has it working on jsFiddle anyway. It needs to work locally.

Comment: It's working locally for me - the link is to the code that is working for me

Comment: Ah OK, I guess that might be helpful then :)

Comment: It works here same as the jsfiddle: http://fotest.co.nf/

Answer (score 2):

Err, you have to include Jquery library src, are you?

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 2):

you are not importing jquery lib

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to remove syntax error like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".black").hover(function () {
        $(".orange").toggle();
    });
});
```

and check that have you added js file or not,and whether it is loaded or not,if not added try to add this at the header

```
<link type='text/javascript' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js' />
```

Comment: Did it, does not help. Which is what I'm getting really frustrated about.

Comment: Just see the console and post us what errors you got..??

Comment: @user1925923 Please paste the HTML and JS files *exactly* as they are to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you add jquery 1.9.1.js ?

If no, Please add it.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

Answer (score 1):

I do not see you including the jquery script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can also leave off the protocol part; if some parts of the site use SSL the reference will automatically pickup the `https:` it needs.

Comment: I'd keep the protocol. He's a beginner and if he opens it from the file explorer, the protocol will default to `file://` and the browser won't find the file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting $ is not defined error.So you have to add the jquery plugin to use jquery methods.